# Azure Cloud Service unable to connect to SQL Database on write operations only

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, database-connection, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have developed a web application in lightswitch. There is an HTML lightswitch client that connects to a server (C#) and this server gets the data from an SQL Database.

The application is working correctly in my local machine, the problem comes when I publish the solution to a Cloud Service in Azure. Then, the server connects to the database correctly and can read all the information from it, but when I try to update the database from within my application (insert or update rows) the application freezes and it promts the following error:

> > Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
> >     Inner exception message:
> >     Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
> >     Inner exception message:
> >     A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have checked the connection parameters and all of them are correct, this is the connection string in my web.config:

```
<add name="My_Data" connectionString="data source=tcp:{MyServer}.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog={myDatabase};user id={Myuser}@{MyServer};password={MyPassword};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have seen other questions with the same issue, but all of them were because the database or the server was not available. I have no problem connecting to the server because I can query my database with no problems.

The error comes when I try to write in my database, either because I click on the save button of a lightswitch screen or because I do it by code in the server:

```
serverContext.DataWorkspace.My_Data.SaveChanges();
```

If I comment the previous line, the error is not prompted.

I have also checked the user permissions in the database and this usser is a db_owner, so there should be no problem with that.

Anyone has ever faced a problem like this?

Comment: Maybe your SQL server doesnt allow access to your service. On your windows azure portal go to the SQL server, under the "configure" tab check if "WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES" is set to "yes".

Comment: Thanks for your comment ;) I already checked that. Actually, I can connect to the database because i can read data from it. The problem is that I can't write in my database.

Comment: ok, maybe its your code then. do you call dispose the dbcontext before calling the save ? did you try "only" saving data without first reading it ?

Comment: I don't use the dispose method, instead I put my code inside of a `using(var serverContext = ServerApplicationContext.CreateContext()){}` I tried only writing in the database and it is not working either

Comment: I try to understand why you have this issues. what if you use a simplified connection string like this : `<add name="My_Data" connectionString="data source=tcp:{MyServer}.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog={myDatabase};user id={Myuser}@{MyServer};password={MyPassword}; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`, did you try using this or your connection string from your local machine ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to do that. It works in my local machine but it does not in Azure... I am really stuck here

Comment: You've resolved the issue, so this comment is only for completeness' sake. I'd suggest that since you can **read** but not **write**, the identity you're using to log in to the DB has *db_datareader* but not *db_datawriter* scheme. But you've figured it out yourself already, right? I had an analogue issue and find out that when I change the name of my user in the connection string, the reporter log in failure still had the old user name - meaning: I wasn't logging in with the credentials I thought I did. Stupid computer/Azure tried to "help"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

After a deep research, I discovered that Azure server is adding a connection string to my application (I don't know how nor why). This connection string is inherited from somewhere and it is pointing to a local instance of SQL Express. Obviously, this instance does not exist, so after a timeout the application throws the error shown above.

I don't really know why this is happening nor why only happens when I try to write in my database. The solution I found is to add the following in the connection strings part of my web.config:

```
<clear />
```

With this, we delete the inherited connection string. And now, we have to set the connection string of the LocalSqlServer (which will be our connection string, the one that points to our remote SQL Server in Azure):

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source={SERVER}.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog={DATABASE};Integrated Security=False;User ID={USER}@{SERVER};Password={PASSWORD};Encrypt=True" />
```

Now, everything works fine. I hope this can help anyone who faces the same problem than me and I would really like to know why this happened, so if anyone knows it, please tell me :)